# Django how to call a choice field in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model field with choices. Like this:

```
CHAIN_CHOICES = (
        ('P','Public'),
        ('N','Private')
        )
        chain = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHAIN_CHOICES, verbose_name=u"Chain")
```

In my template I would like to call it simillary to this:

```
<li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></i> <span>{{mymodel.chain}}</span></li>
```

Problem is .... this is calling 'N' or 'P' and I would like to call the 'Public' - 'Private' values. 
Any hint would be wellcome.

Regards,

J.M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess I have found my answer:

```
{{ mymodel.get_chain_display }}
```

Unless there is a different way ??

Answer (score 0):

@JanMejor 
I want to call from templates to "choices" too but without duplicates. Here is a different way you did:

```
...
{% for i in mymodel %}
    {{ i.chain }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Still, it will show duplicates if you have couple posts with the same "choice value"

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. In my case I was listing all posts and "choice" field was just one of many others. Do you need to show just a list of values in your choice field ?